# Error when trying to create a framework in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I am having trouble as the creation of frameworks and use them in my project, for a better visualization of all, I would put all steps I did to the creation of the framework:

First I create new framework: **New > Framework & Library > Cocoa Touch Framework** called **MyFramework**

Second I create a class name called **MyAlerts** (Son of NSObject) the struct of the class is:

**MyAlerts.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyAlerts : NSObject

-(void)doAlert;

@end
```

**MyAlerts.m**

```
#import "MyAlerts.h"

@implementation MyAlerts

-(void)doAlert{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

@end
```

After created, I go to **MyProject > Build Phases > Headers** and add the class **MyAlerts.h** into the **Public Tab**, like the image below:

[image]

After That I Compile and Run my framework for both devices: **iOS Device** and **iPhone6**, Then I went up to the products folder and open the framework in finder.

Now all I did was create a new project , and within this project I imported the file **MyFramework.framework** (which was located within the folder **iphonesimulator**), The next step was going to **MyProject > General**  and drag and drop the framework file into the **embedded binaries**.

Now when I import the framework and try to access the MyAlerts Class:

```
#import <MyFramework/MyFramework.h>
 MyAlerts *alerts = [[MyAlerts alloc] init];
 [alerts doAlert];
```

Xcode Give me 3 erros:

```
<module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'MyFramework' does not include header 'MyAlerts.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
#import "/Users/TesteUSERS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyFramework-bdznaeqxcmsracfkbohifrjyxnrb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyFramework.framework/Headers/MyFramework.h"
error: use of undeclared identifier 'MyAlerts'
```

To try to solve this problem I do the following things:

> Go to MyProject > Build Phases > Target Dependencies and try to add my framework but he doesn't appear.
>
> Go to Header Search Paths and add the code "$(SRCROOT)/../MyFramework/MyFramework"

When I do this the framework works well, But Have a little problem, When I do that (Use that code inside header Search Paths) my project compile and the alert was shown (because I'm accessing the framework folder), now if I delete the framework file (that I import to my project) The alert continue showing.

In my case I want to access the framework from the file that I'm imported and not through the **header search paths**.

What am I doing wrong ?

> EDIT -> Works Great Now

After many and many hours trying to solve this problem finally I found an answer:

All I need to do is, go to MyFramework project and inside MyFramework.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//! Project version number for MyFramework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double MyFrameworkVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for MyFramework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char MyFrameworkVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <MyFramework/PublicHeader.h>
```

Add this line of code:

```
#import <MyFramework/MyAlerts.h>
```

Compile and run again (will be update the MyFramework.framework)

Return to TestFramework and forget that things what I said to try to resolve the problem **(The problem is not inside the Build Phases and header search paths)**.

Now to use the framework You need to use this code:

```
#import <MyFramework/MyAlerts.h>//You Need to import the class that you want to use in my case MyAlerts.h

//And Finally you can do an alert

MyAlerts *alerts = [[MyAlerts alloc] init];
    [alerts doAlert];
```